# Watch OS 2 Native app Bluetooth device connection

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, native, watchkit, watchos-2

As the title states: I want to create an native Watch OS2 app and communicate with  bluetooth devices. I know Watch OS 2 can pair with wireless headsets (BLE) and 'health devices' but do developers have access to use this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a bit late for answer, but following these links: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25759

[Objective C-Is it possible to connect to BLE devices from iWatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568770/objective-c-is-it-possible-to-connect-to-ble-devices-from-iwatch)

It's not possible to access `CoreBluetooth` on watchOS2. Use `WatchConnectivity` to communicate with parent device.